# Can not install Ubuntu (13.04 / 12.04) due to ext4 error

Tags: installation, partitioning, ext4

I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop 64bit Edition on my new PC. (1TB SATA HDD)
I set my mainboard to use BIOS to boot up.

At first I tried installing next to Windows 7, got errors.
Now I tried to install it directly without having any Windows on it --> Same Error

When selecting my timezone a popup showed up, saying that it wasn't able to mount /dev/sda3 with ext4.

When opening the little console in the Installation menu, the error

> VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

showed up.

Thanks in advance for any help on the question: How to I fix this error to install Ubuntu on my machine.

EDIT: I also tried using Ubuntu 13.04 with the same errors.
Discs were burned on a Mac and also verified using the burning tool as well as the "Check Disk" option on the disks.

EDIT2: I tried to make the partitions on my own (20 GB ext4 as / ; 8GB Swap; Rest as /home ext4) and I also tried to let Ubuntu create the partitions.

EDIT3: Installing Windows works without problems (so it might not be the HDD?)

Comment: This post may help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16029/37944

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Thanks, but it seems that this is about trying to rescue his data, right? My problem is, rather, to install Ubuntu (as I have no important data on my system right now). But I can't even install Ubuntu on my empty HDD. (Sorry if I got anything wrong)

Comment: do you have a UEFI BIOS?

Comment: @Cubiq yes, but I disabled the UEFI stuff to solely boot with BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: just for completeness this has been fixed by adding `pci=noaer,nomsi` boot parameters to the `/etc/default/grub` file. The problem is probably caused by a motherboard BIOS issue (follow the comments below).

---

This can be caused by a variety of reasons. It could even be a bug in your motherboard BIOS.

If you have a UEFI motherboard and you can destroy the data in your HD, boot in EUFI mode and try to create a GPT partition table.

Run the live cd and open Gparted. Select the drive, unmount all mounted partitions in that drive and select from the menu `Device > Create Partition Table...`. From the list of available partitions select `GPT`.

If you don't have a UEFI bios try the same but re-create a standard MBR/MSDOS partition (selected by default).

Now retry to install and let Ubuntu create the partitions for you.

Comment: Okay, I booted in UEFI (disabled all BIOS options). I created a GPT Table. GParted now shows /dev/sda as unallocated, giving an error '/dev/sda: unrecognized disk label'. What can I do?

Comment: is the installer able to run on the drive now?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work on this disk. It also doesn't work, if I set up gpt and the partitions using a GParted Live DVD. It then gives "THe attempt to mount a file system with type ext4 in SCSI5 (0,1,0), partition #1(sda) at / failed."

Comment: can you check the HD with fsck.ext4? can you also try to change SATA port?

Comment: Checked the partitions with fsck.ext4 --> No Errors

Changed the SATA Port and tried to reinstall, partitioning with the GParted Live DVD. Installation shows the same error as before :-(

Comment: @Franz just out of curiosity can you try to boot adding pci=noaer,nomsi to the boot string?

Comment: Thank you sir! This parameters fixed it and it now works!