# the attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, uefi, ext4

newbie to linux/ubuntu enviorment, trying to install ubuntu but during the installation processing after selecting the region then it propts an error "the attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 failed".
When I select the disk check option in ubuntu then then it shown me 2 error caught while checking.
I search the net thoroughly and found that this is occurs due to BIOS setting, [Can not install Ubuntu (13.04 / 12.04) due to ext4 error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334689/can-not-install-ubuntu-13-04-12-04-due-to-ext4-error)
Now the problem is earlier I had windows which is corrupted during the unsuccessful installation process of ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso,now I want only OS ubuntu in my system, after more than 100 attemps I fail, pls help me to install ubuntu step by step and also tell me the how does UEFI bios affects this installation process.
My system config is: 
gigabyte 970a-ds3p motherboard/ 
amd fx6300/ 
12gb RAM

Comment: Is this the only OS that you want on your system?

Comment: yes sir..only ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64

Comment: when you tried to install ubuntu 15.04 desktop did you by chance reformat the drive that you wanted to install the OS on?

Comment: no I didn't ...

Comment: Would you like me to make a step by step tutorial with pictures?

Comment: sure sir, shall be highly obliged :)

Comment: it seems it is all due to some bios setting,and I am just unable to change it,u can mail me solution @ ketanmehta4u@gmail.com

Comment: Did you try the (only) answer to the [question you mentioned](/q/334689/175814)? If so, what was the outcome?

Answer (score -1):

I have found this [tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-15-04-desktop-and-server/) online and I think this is just what you are looking for. The tutorial will walk you through the steps on installing and setting up the OS. Only follow the part where it says "Install Ubuntu 15.04 desktop" **DO NOT** follow the part below where it says "Install Ubuntu 15.04 server" that is if you are going to be using it as some sort of server (as the OS implies) such as a file server or a web server.

I really hope this helps you out.

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful if this helps you out.

Comment: after selecting the the country I am getting " the attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 failed " message.

Comment: did you follow the tutorial I sent you?

Comment: yes...already doing the same thing ... requires to change bios setting.. don't know how to change

Comment: are you booting from a usb stick or a dvd drive?

Comment: usb using universal installer

Comment: can you try to reset your bios to factory default?

Comment: already done... but still the same problem.. generally this problem occur with motherboard with UEFI feature.

Comment: can you turn off the UEFI bios option and put it in legacy mode?

Comment: how????????????

Comment: I think I have found it you have to disable Disable Secure Boot here is the link where I found that [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/)

Comment: i will do it tomorrow, time to sleep, it is already 2:45 am. thanks 4 ur kind help. c u tomorrow

Comment: It should be on the security tab in the bios Something like "Secure boot" and disable it.

Comment: It should be in the tab called "Bios Features" and then if you scroll down a little bit until you see a option called "Secure Boot Control" you want to disable that and try it again.

Comment: tried almost every method but fail... it seems I have to install Windows again :( :(

Comment: Try to clear the CMOS on the bios. If you do not know how to do that look in the motherboard manual.